# WebRTC screen share not working on LTE in USA

Tags: android, webrtc, stun, turn

I am developing one Android application for remote screen share using webRTC. For STUN servers I used google stun server. It is working well on WIFI and LTE in India. In USA it's not working on LTE, but it's working on WIFI.

First, I used only STUN server and then now combined STUN and TURN servers, but no use .

Below is my code,

```
val iceServers = ArrayList<PeerConnection.IceServer>()
iceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"))
iceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:13.250.13.83:3478?transport=udp", "YzYNCouZM1mhqhmseWk6", "YzYNCouZM1mhqhmseWk6"))
return iceServers
```

Still, this is not working in USA on LTE.

Is this GOOGLE stun server doesn't work for USA in LTE?

Comment: Have you tried other STUN servers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20068944/295004

Comment: Tried with url:'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302', but no use.                                                  Is there anything like some servers wont work in USA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check network connections with STUN, TURN

Check these two links in latest Chrome in mobile.

https://networktest.twilio.com

https://test.webrtc.org

Probably you can check the network is okay or not.

### Maybe IPv6 Problem

Also in Korea, I have some problem with IPv6 LTE mobile clients. Sometimes mobile carrier give IPv6 to their clients, then P2P connection does not work. Maybe there is same problem on there.

I solved with TURN + TCP. I don't know why, but IPv6 clients are not works with UDP.

Here are some related documents:

- [Webrtc media over tcp?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44707489/)

  > **To force strict TCP via TURN server:**
  >
  > - Use only TURN url with `?transport=tcp`
  > - Specify `iceTransportPolicy:"relay"`, so that all media will flow via TURN
- [TURN, STUN setting](https://www.red5pro.com/docs/server/turnstun.html)

  > Provide TURN and STUN functionality over TCP and UDP:
  >
  > ```
  > sudo turnserver -L <your STUN server\'s IP address> -o -a -f -r red5pro.com
  > ```
  >
  > To run the server without TCP:
  >
  > ```
  > sudo turnserver -L <your STUN server\'s IP address> -o -a -f --no-tcp --no-tcp-relay -r red5pro.com
  > ```
  >
  > To run STUN only over UDP:
  >
  > ```
  > sudo turnserver -L <your STUN server\'s IP address> -o -a -f --stun-only --no-tcp --no-tcp-relay -r red5pro.com
  > ```
- [What happens when WebRTC shifts to TURN over TCP](https://testrtc.com/happens-webrtc-shifts-turn-tcp/)

Comment: If its Ipv6, do we have any work around to make WebRTC to work?

Comment: I add some more practice